# Is there a better way to do this in PHP

Tags: php

i am using this code to generate rows depending on the value in the database, I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this but I'm unsure how!

```
if ($empty == 1) {
    echo "<li class='col-sm-4'><div class='horse-wrap empty'>Empty</div></li>";
}
if ($empty == 2) {
    echo "<li class='col-sm-4'><div class='horse-wrap empty'>Empty</div></li>";
    echo "<li class='col-sm-4'><div class='horse-wrap empty'>Empty</div></li>";
}
if ($empty == 3) {
    echo "<li class='col-sm-4'><div class='horse-wrap empty'>Empty</div></li>";
    echo "<li class='col-sm-4'><div class='horse-wrap empty'>Empty</div></li>";
    echo "<li class='col-sm-4'><div class='horse-wrap empty'>Empty</div></li>";
}
if ($empty == 4) {
    echo "<li class='col-sm-4'><div class='horse-wrap empty'>Empty</div></li>";
    echo "<li class='col-sm-4'><div class='horse-wrap empty'>Empty</div></li>";
    echo "<li class='col-sm-4'><div class='horse-wrap empty'>Empty</div></li>";
    echo "<li class='col-sm-4'><div class='horse-wrap empty'>Empty</div></li>";
}
```

Comment: Use switch for this.

Comment: can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it using for loop:

```
$empty = 5;
$str = '';
for(i=0;$i<$empty;$i++) {
    $str .= "<li class='col-sm-4'><div class='horse-wrap empty'>Empty</div></li>";
}
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) for that:

```
if ($empty > 0) {
    echo str_repeat("<li class='col-sm-4'><div class='horse-wrap empty'>Empty</div></li>", $empty);
}
```

Comment: To be honest, no need for the `if(){}`. `str_repeat()` outputs nothing if a zero is supplied.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Why execute function when you don't need that? It's faster to check first

Comment: That's true I guess. With 1,000,000 iterations on PHP 7.0.5, the performance difference is about 0.056 seconds in favor of the `if()` clause.

Comment: Another tidbit, if `$empty` **is** greater than zero then the `if()` statement actually adds time to the processing.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from your question, you need use a loop :

```
<?php
  $empty = 4;
  for( $i = 0; $i < $empty; $i ++){
   echo "<li class='col-sm-4'><div class='horse-wrap empty'>Empty</div></li>";
  }
```

This code will show as many empty rows as you need. And `$empty` is count of them.